# Boot Repair Disk 64-bit doesn't boot!

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

So I have a UEFI system from 2013, fast boot is disabled and all that, and secure boot is turned off. I just burned a fresh copy of Boot Repair Disk since I don't have a USB thumb drive, but my system doesn't detect the disk drive as being bootable. Nothing in the EFI firmware shows the optical disk drive as a boot option before I even get anything up. I opened up the disk in Windows Explorer to see that the disk does have an EFI folder and EFI boot files. So what's the problem?

Comment: Is your question really "how do I make my computer boot from DVD?"

Comment: No, the question is "why won't boot-repair boot on my UEFI computer". I have a similar problem doing this.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry it would have helped had OP stated all other DVD's boot ok. I can empathize because I all kinds of problems trying to get Live USB to boot but Live DVD booted no problem.

Comment: Try changing your BIOS from UEFI mode, to CSM/Legacy and see if the Boot Repair disc will boot. Set your BIOS back to the setting you found it in when you're done.

Comment: If I set the BIOS to CSM and boot, then try and fix the boot if it works, will it write grub to an MBR record?

Comment: Okay, so I got it to boot from CSM, and I tried boot repair, here are the results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23546973/

'sda' is SSD with the EFI partition I want to put grub on. 'sdb' contains an HDD that I previously used for linux until I dd'd the main installation to the SSD, all it contains now is the swap. 'sdd' contains an external HDD that I use to troubleshoot the PC running Windows. I don't want to fidget with its EFI partition.

Comment: Yeah it still doesn't boot. Also, now my Windows won't boot because of an IRQ error.

Comment: Did you remember to set your BIOS back to UEFI before booting Windows? I'll post a longer reply in a new answer...

Comment: The recommendation to activate BIOS/CSM/legacy support was *bad advice!* Your computer was booting Windows in EFI/UEFI mode, and booting Boot Repair in BIOS mode might have installed GRUB in BIOS mode, but getting the two boot modes to coexist is difficult. My guess is that the Boot Repair image you got was improperly prepared, so instead, I recommend running the tool from an *EFI-mode* boot of an Ubuntu installation disc in its "try before installing" mode. If that doesn't work, try installing my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set your BIOS back to UEFI to boot your normal operating systems.

If for some reason that doesn't allow you to boot normally, then you'll need to run boot-repair in UEFI mode.

- make sure your BIOS is set back to UEFI
- boot a Ubuntu Live DVD in `Try Ubuntu` mode
- make sure that you're connected to the Internet
- start the `terminal` application from the Unity launcher
- in the terminal, type:

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
  sudo boot-repair

Perform the recommended repair.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49436/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-boot-repair-disk-64-bit-doesnt-boot).